# Перенос слов в QListWidgetItem, во избежание прокрутки по горизонтали

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtextedit, qlistwidget, wordwrap

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать перенос текста `wordWrap` в `QListWidget`?
Мне нужно сделать перенос слова `test...test` до какой то границы, и далее переносить на другую строчку.

Как это сделать? `WordWrap` не работает.

Код дизайна:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(621, 463)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(8, 6, 591, 451))
        self.frame.setStyleSheet("background:#1a1a1a; border-radius:7px;")
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setLineWidth(0)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(390, 330, 41, 31))
        self.pushButton.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
"border: 2px solid #666;\n"
"background-color: #404040;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover{\n"
"border: 2px solid #666;\n"
"background-color: #3b3b3b;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed{\n"
"border: 2px solid white;\n"
"background-color: #444444;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton.setText("")
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("icons/send_icon.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.pushButton.setIcon(icon)
        self.pushButton.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(18, 20))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.frame)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 330, 371, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.lineEdit_2.setFont(font)
        self.lineEdit_2.setStyleSheet("border: 2px solid #666;\n"
"background-color: #3b3b3b;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;")
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.frame)
        self.lineEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 370, 81, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.lineEdit_3.setFont(font)
        self.lineEdit_3.setStyleSheet("border: 2px solid #666;\n"
"background-color: #3b3b3b;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;")
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
        self.lineEdit_4 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.frame)
        self.lineEdit_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 370, 121, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.lineEdit_4.setFont(font)
        self.lineEdit_4.setStyleSheet("border: 2px solid #666;\n"
"background-color: #3b3b3b;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;")
        self.lineEdit_4.setObjectName("lineEdit_4")
        self.lineEdit_5 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.frame)
        self.lineEdit_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 370, 201, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.lineEdit_5.setFont(font)
        self.lineEdit_5.setStyleSheet("border: 2px solid #666;\n"
"background-color: #3b3b3b;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;")
        self.lineEdit_5.setObjectName("lineEdit_5")
        self.pushButton_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.pushButton_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 410, 211, 31))
        self.pushButton_5.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_5.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
"border: 2px solid #666;\n"
"background-color: #404040;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover{\n"
"border: 2px solid #666;\n"
"background-color: #3b3b3b;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed{\n"
"border: 2px solid white;\n"
"background-color: #444444;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
"}")
        icon1 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon1.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("icons/connect_icon.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.pushButton_5.setIcon(icon1)
        self.pushButton_5.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(24, 24))
        self.pushButton_5.setCheckable(False)
        self.pushButton_5.setChecked(False)
        self.pushButton_5.setAutoExclusive(False)
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")
        self.pushButton_7 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.pushButton_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 410, 201, 31))
        self.pushButton_7.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_7.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
"border: 2px solid #666;\n"
"background-color: #404040;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover{\n"
"border: 2px solid #666;\n"
"background-color: #3b3b3b;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed{\n"
"border: 2px solid white;\n"
"background-color: #444444;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
"}")
        icon2 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon2.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("icons/light.ico"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.pushButton_7.setIcon(icon2)
        self.pushButton_7.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(24, 24))
        self.pushButton_7.setObjectName("pushButton_7")
        self.smile_1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.smile_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(440, 330, 41, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.smile_1.setFont(font)
        self.smile_1.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.smile_1.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
"border: 2px solid #666;\n"
"background-color: #404040;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover{\n"
"border: 2px solid #666;\n"
"background-color: #3b3b3b;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed{\n"
"border: 2px solid white;\n"
"background-color: #444444;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
"}")
        self.smile_1.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(18, 20))
        self.smile_1.setObjectName("smile_1")
        self.smile_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.smile_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(490, 330, 41, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.smile_2.setFont(font)
        self.smile_2.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.smile_2.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
"border: 2px solid #666;\n"
"background-color: #404040;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover{\n"
"border: 2px solid #666;\n"
"background-color: #3b3b3b;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed{\n"
"border: 2px solid white;\n"
"background-color: #444444;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
"}")
        self.smile_2.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(18, 20))
        self.smile_2.setObjectName("smile_2")
        self.smile_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.smile_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(540, 330, 41, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.smile_3.setFont(font)
        self.smile_3.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.smile_3.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
"border: 2px solid #666;\n"
"background-color: #404040;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover{\n"
"border: 2px solid #666;\n"
"background-color: #3b3b3b;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed{\n"
"border: 2px solid white;\n"
"background-color: #444444;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
"}")
        self.smile_3.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(18, 20))
        self.smile_3.setObjectName("smile_3")
        self.smile_6 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.smile_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(540, 370, 41, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.smile_6.setFont(font)
        self.smile_6.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.smile_6.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
"border: 2px solid #666;\n"
"background-color: #404040;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover{\n"
"border: 2px solid #666;\n"
"background-color: #3b3b3b;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed{\n"
"border: 2px solid white;\n"
"background-color: #444444;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
"}")
        self.smile_6.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(18, 20))
        self.smile_6.setObjectName("smile_6")
        self.smile_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.smile_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(490, 370, 41, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.smile_5.setFont(font)
        self.smile_5.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.smile_5.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
"border: 2px solid #666;\n"
"background-color: #404040;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover{\n"
"border: 2px solid #666;\n"
"background-color: #3b3b3b;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed{\n"
"border: 2px solid white;\n"
"background-color: #444444;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
"}")
        self.smile_5.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(18, 20))
        self.smile_5.setObjectName("smile_5")
        self.smile_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.smile_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(440, 370, 41, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.smile_4.setFont(font)
        self.smile_4.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.smile_4.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
"border: 2px solid #666;\n"
"background-color: #404040;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover{\n"
"border: 2px solid #666;\n"
"background-color: #3b3b3b;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed{\n"
"border: 2px solid white;\n"
"background-color: #444444;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
"}")
        self.smile_4.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(18, 20))
        self.smile_4.setObjectName("smile_4")
        self.smile_9 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.smile_9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(540, 410, 41, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.smile_9.setFont(font)
        self.smile_9.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.smile_9.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
"border: 2px solid #666;\n"
"background-color: #404040;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover{\n"
"border: 2px solid #666;\n"
"background-color: #3b3b3b;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed{\n"
"border: 2px solid white;\n"
"background-color: #444444;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
"}")
        self.smile_9.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(18, 20))
        self.smile_9.setObjectName("smile_9")
        self.smile_8 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.smile_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(490, 410, 41, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.smile_8.setFont(font)
        self.smile_8.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.smile_8.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
"border: 2px solid #666;\n"
"background-color: #404040;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover{\n"
"border: 2px solid #666;\n"
"background-color: #3b3b3b;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed{\n"
"border: 2px solid white;\n"
"background-color: #444444;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
"}")
        self.smile_8.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(18, 20))
        self.smile_8.setObjectName("smile_8")
        self.smile_7 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.smile_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(440, 410, 41, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.smile_7.setFont(font)
        self.smile_7.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.smile_7.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
"border: 2px solid #666;\n"
"background-color: #404040;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover{\n"
"border: 2px solid #666;\n"
"background-color: #3b3b3b;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed{\n"
"border: 2px solid white;\n"
"background-color: #444444;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
"}")
        self.smile_7.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(18, 20))
        self.smile_7.setObjectName("smile_7")
        self.frame_2 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.frame)
        self.frame_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 591, 31))
        self.frame_2.setStyleSheet("background:rgb(44, 44, 44); border-radius: 7px;")
        self.frame_2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_2.setObjectName("frame_2")
        self.title1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame_2)
        self.title1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(12, 6, 361, 22))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS Shell Dlg 2")
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.title1.setFont(font)
        self.title1.setStyleSheet("color: #fff;")
        self.title1.setObjectName("title1")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame_2)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(550, 0, 41, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton_2.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_2.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
"\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover{\n"
"background-color:rgb(199, 0, 0);\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed{\n"
"border: 2px solid white;;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"background:rgb(199, 0, 0);\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame_2)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(510, 0, 40, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton_3.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_3.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_3.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover{\n"
"background-color:rgb(102, 102, 102);\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed{\n"
"border: 2px solid white;;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"background-color:rgb(102, 102, 102);\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.title1.raise_()
        self.pushButton_3.raise_()
        self.pushButton_2.raise_()
        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.frame)
        self.listWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 40, 571, 281))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        font.setKerning(False)
        self.listWidget.setFont(font)
        self.listWidget.setTabletTracking(False)
        self.listWidget.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.listWidget.setStyleSheet("QListWidget{\n"
"border: 2px solid #666;\n"
"background-color: #3b3b3b;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
"}\n"
"QListWidget QScrollBar\n"
"{\n"
"background : gray;\n"
"color:black\n"
"}\n"
"")
        self.listWidget.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.listWidget.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Plain)
        self.listWidget.setLineWidth(1)
        self.listWidget.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAsNeeded)
        self.listWidget.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAsNeeded)
        self.listWidget.setSizeAdjustPolicy(QtWidgets.QAbstractScrollArea.AdjustIgnored)
        self.listWidget.setAutoScroll(True)
        self.listWidget.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        self.listWidget.setTabKeyNavigation(False)
        self.listWidget.setProperty("showDropIndicator", True)
        self.listWidget.setDragDropOverwriteMode(False)
        self.listWidget.setAlternatingRowColors(False)
        self.listWidget.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoSelection)
        self.listWidget.setSelectionBehavior(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SelectItems)
        self.listWidget.setTextElideMode(QtCore.Qt.ElideNone)
        self.listWidget.setVerticalScrollMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.ScrollPerItem)
        self.listWidget.setHorizontalScrollMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.ScrollPerItem)
        self.listWidget.setMovement(QtWidgets.QListView.Static)
        self.listWidget.setFlow(QtWidgets.QListView.TopToBottom)
        self.listWidget.setProperty("isWrapping", False)
        self.listWidget.setResizeMode(QtWidgets.QListView.Adjust)
        self.listWidget.setLayoutMode(QtWidgets.QListView.SinglePass)
        self.listWidget.setViewMode(QtWidgets.QListView.ListMode)
        self.listWidget.setUniformItemSizes(False)
        self.listWidget.setWordWrap(True)
        self.listWidget.setSelectionRectVisible(False)
        self.listWidget.setObjectName("listWidget")
        self.lineEdit_2.raise_()
        self.lineEdit_3.raise_()
        self.lineEdit_4.raise_()
        self.lineEdit_5.raise_()
        self.pushButton_5.raise_()
        self.pushButton_7.raise_()
        self.smile_1.raise_()
        self.smile_2.raise_()
        self.smile_3.raise_()
        self.smile_6.raise_()
        self.smile_5.raise_()
        self.smile_4.raise_()
        self.smile_9.raise_()
        self.smile_8.raise_()
        self.smile_7.raise_()
        self.pushButton.raise_()
        self.listWidget.raise_()
        self.frame_2.raise_()
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Chat by Liemore"))
        self.lineEdit_2.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ваше сообщение"))
        self.lineEdit_3.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "Порт"))
        self.lineEdit_4.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "IP"))
        self.lineEdit_5.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ник"))
        self.pushButton_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Подключиться!"))
        self.pushButton_7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Светлый режим"))
        self.smile_1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", ""))
        self.smile_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", ""))
        self.smile_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", ""))
        self.smile_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", ""))
        self.smile_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", ""))
        self.smile_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", ""))
        self.smile_9.setText(_translate("MainWindow", ""))
        self.smile_8.setText(_translate("MainWindow", ""))
        self.smile_7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", ""))
        self.title1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Чат для общения"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "X"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "_"))
        self.listWidget.setSortingEnabled(False)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Tynett, пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: он не нужен, мне просто нужно узнать, что нужно сделать, чтобы слова в qlistwidgetitem переносились

Comment: Tynett, скажите пожалуйста, почему вы решили использовать `QListWidget`, а не например `QTextEdit ` ?

Comment: я хочу показывать сообщения как в дискорде, или стиме(на панельках), а не текстом

Comment: а еще в qtextedit нельзя какую то надпись в правую сторону убрать, а другую в левую

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я не совсем понял вашу задумку с `QListWidget`, но вам виднее.

[**wordWrap**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistview.html#wordWrap-prop) - работает в QListWidget !

> **wordWrap** : bool
>
> Это свойство содержит политику переноса текста элемента.
>
> Если это свойство имеет значение ***true***, то текст элемента переносится там,
> где это необходимо, в местах разрыва слов; в противном случае он вообще не завернут.
> Это свойство по умолчанию имеет значение false.
>
> Обратите внимание, что даже если перенос включен, ячейка не будет расширена,
> чтобы освободить место для текста. Он будет печатать многоточие для текста,
> который не может быть показан, в соответствии с textElideMode представления.

Но ваш тестовый текст - это **`ОДНО слово`**,
которое не имеет место разрыва слов и вам надо
самостоятельно позаботиться о том чтобы вставить эти разрывы, т.е. пробелы.

В этом вам должен помочь `QFontMetrics`

> QFontMetrics QWidget::fontMetrics() const
>
> Возвращает метрики шрифта для текущего шрифта виджета. Эквивалентен QFontMetrics(widget->font()).

Примерно так вы можете определить длину тестового текста:

```
width = self.listWidget.fontMetrics().width(text)
```

При этом вы знаете геометрию вашего `listWidget`:

```
#                                                vvv
self.listWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 40, 571, 281))
```

Теперь вам нужно написать алгоритм, который разобьет
ваш тестовый текст так как вам надо.

В моем примере, я лишь отлавливаю слово, которое не помещается и
разбиваю его на два слова, деля его пополам.

Вот тестовый текст:

```
Если это свойство имеет значение True, то текст элемента переносится там, где это необходимо, в местах разрыва слов; в противном случае текст не переносится.
```

Второй тестовый текст - тот же текст, но с убранными пробелами.

---

**main.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(621, 463)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(8, 6, 591, 451))
        self.frame.setStyleSheet("background:#1a1a1a; border-radius:7px;")
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setLineWidth(0)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(390, 330, 41, 31))
        self.pushButton.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
"border: 2px solid #666;\n"
"background-color: #404040;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover{\n"
"border: 2px solid #666;\n"
"background-color: #3b3b3b;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed{\n"
"border: 2px solid white;\n"
"background-color: #444444;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton.setText("")
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("icons/send_icon.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.pushButton.setIcon(icon)
        self.pushButton.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(18, 20))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.frame)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 330, 371, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.lineEdit_2.setFont(font)
        self.lineEdit_2.setStyleSheet("border: 2px solid #666;\n"
"background-color: #3b3b3b;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;")
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")

        self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.frame)
        self.lineEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 370, 81, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.lineEdit_3.setFont(font)
        self.lineEdit_3.setStyleSheet("border: 2px solid #666;\n"
"background-color: #3b3b3b;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;")
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
        
        self.lineEdit_4 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.frame)
        self.lineEdit_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 370, 121, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.lineEdit_4.setFont(font)
        self.lineEdit_4.setStyleSheet("border: 2px solid #666;\n"
"background-color: #3b3b3b;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;")
        self.lineEdit_4.setObjectName("lineEdit_4")
        
        self.lineEdit_5 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.frame)
        self.lineEdit_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 370, 201, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.lineEdit_5.setFont(font)
        self.lineEdit_5.setStyleSheet("border: 2px solid #666;\n"
"background-color: #3b3b3b;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;")
        self.lineEdit_5.setObjectName("lineEdit_5")
        
        self.pushButton_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.pushButton_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 410, 211, 31))
        self.pushButton_5.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_5.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
"border: 2px solid #666;\n"
"background-color: #404040;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover{\n"
"border: 2px solid #666;\n"
"background-color: #3b3b3b;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed{\n"
"border: 2px solid white;\n"
"background-color: #444444;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
"}")
        icon1 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon1.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("icons/connect_icon.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.pushButton_5.setIcon(icon1)
        self.pushButton_5.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(24, 24))
        self.pushButton_5.setCheckable(False)
        self.pushButton_5.setChecked(False)
        self.pushButton_5.setAutoExclusive(False)
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")
        self.pushButton_7 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.pushButton_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 410, 201, 31))
        self.pushButton_7.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_7.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
"border: 2px solid #666;\n"
"background-color: #404040;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover{\n"
"border: 2px solid #666;\n"
"background-color: #3b3b3b;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed{\n"
"border: 2px solid white;\n"
"background-color: #444444;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
"}")
        icon2 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon2.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("icons/light.ico"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.pushButton_7.setIcon(icon2)
        self.pushButton_7.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(24, 24))
        self.pushButton_7.setObjectName("pushButton_7")
        self.smile_1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.smile_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(440, 330, 41, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.smile_1.setFont(font)
        self.smile_1.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.smile_1.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
"border: 2px solid #666;\n"
"background-color: #404040;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover{\n"
"border: 2px solid #666;\n"
"background-color: #3b3b3b;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed{\n"
"border: 2px solid white;\n"
"background-color: #444444;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
"}")
        self.smile_1.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(18, 20))
        self.smile_1.setObjectName("smile_1")
        self.smile_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.smile_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(490, 330, 41, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.smile_2.setFont(font)
        self.smile_2.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.smile_2.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
"border: 2px solid #666;\n"
"background-color: #404040;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover{\n"
"border: 2px solid #666;\n"
"background-color: #3b3b3b;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed{\n"
"border: 2px solid white;\n"
"background-color: #444444;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
"}")
        self.smile_2.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(18, 20))
        self.smile_2.setObjectName("smile_2")
        self.smile_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.smile_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(540, 330, 41, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.smile_3.setFont(font)
        self.smile_3.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.smile_3.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
"border: 2px solid #666;\n"
"background-color: #404040;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover{\n"
"border: 2px solid #666;\n"
"background-color: #3b3b3b;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed{\n"
"border: 2px solid white;\n"
"background-color: #444444;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
"}")
        self.smile_3.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(18, 20))
        self.smile_3.setObjectName("smile_3")
        self.smile_6 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.smile_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(540, 370, 41, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.smile_6.setFont(font)
        self.smile_6.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.smile_6.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
"border: 2px solid #666;\n"
"background-color: #404040;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover{\n"
"border: 2px solid #666;\n"
"background-color: #3b3b3b;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed{\n"
"border: 2px solid white;\n"
"background-color: #444444;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
"}")
        self.smile_6.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(18, 20))
        self.smile_6.setObjectName("smile_6")
        self.smile_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.smile_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(490, 370, 41, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.smile_5.setFont(font)
        self.smile_5.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.smile_5.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
"border: 2px solid #666;\n"
"background-color: #404040;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover{\n"
"border: 2px solid #666;\n"
"background-color: #3b3b3b;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed{\n"
"border: 2px solid white;\n"
"background-color: #444444;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
"}")
        self.smile_5.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(18, 20))
        self.smile_5.setObjectName("smile_5")
        self.smile_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.smile_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(440, 370, 41, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.smile_4.setFont(font)
        self.smile_4.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.smile_4.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
"border: 2px solid #666;\n"
"background-color: #404040;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover{\n"
"border: 2px solid #666;\n"
"background-color: #3b3b3b;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed{\n"
"border: 2px solid white;\n"
"background-color: #444444;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
"}")
        self.smile_4.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(18, 20))
        self.smile_4.setObjectName("smile_4")
        self.smile_9 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.smile_9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(540, 410, 41, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.smile_9.setFont(font)
        self.smile_9.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.smile_9.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
"border: 2px solid #666;\n"
"background-color: #404040;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover{\n"
"border: 2px solid #666;\n"
"background-color: #3b3b3b;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed{\n"
"border: 2px solid white;\n"
"background-color: #444444;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
"}")
        self.smile_9.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(18, 20))
        self.smile_9.setObjectName("smile_9")
        self.smile_8 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.smile_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(490, 410, 41, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.smile_8.setFont(font)
        self.smile_8.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.smile_8.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
"border: 2px solid #666;\n"
"background-color: #404040;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover{\n"
"border: 2px solid #666;\n"
"background-color: #3b3b3b;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed{\n"
"border: 2px solid white;\n"
"background-color: #444444;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
"}")
        self.smile_8.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(18, 20))
        self.smile_8.setObjectName("smile_8")
        self.smile_7 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.smile_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(440, 410, 41, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.smile_7.setFont(font)
        self.smile_7.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.smile_7.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
"border: 2px solid #666;\n"
"background-color: #404040;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover{\n"
"border: 2px solid #666;\n"
"background-color: #3b3b3b;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed{\n"
"border: 2px solid white;\n"
"background-color: #444444;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
"}")
        self.smile_7.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(18, 20))
        self.smile_7.setObjectName("smile_7")
        
        self.frame_2 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.frame)
        self.frame_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 591, 31))
        self.frame_2.setStyleSheet("background:rgb(44, 44, 44); border-radius: 7px;")
        self.frame_2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_2.setObjectName("frame_2")
        self.title1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame_2)
        self.title1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(12, 6, 361, 22))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS Shell Dlg 2")
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.title1.setFont(font)
        self.title1.setStyleSheet("color: #fff;")
        self.title1.setObjectName("title1")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame_2)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(550, 0, 41, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton_2.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_2.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
"\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover{\n"
"background-color:rgb(199, 0, 0);\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed{\n"
"border: 2px solid white;;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"background:rgb(199, 0, 0);\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame_2)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(510, 0, 40, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton_3.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_3.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_3.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover{\n"
"background-color:rgb(102, 102, 102);\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed{\n"
"border: 2px solid white;;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"background-color:rgb(102, 102, 102);\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.title1.raise_()
        self.pushButton_3.raise_()
        self.pushButton_2.raise_()
        
        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.frame)
        self.listWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 40, 571, 281))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        font.setKerning(False)
        self.listWidget.setFont(font)
        
        self.listWidget.setTabletTracking(False)
        self.listWidget.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.listWidget.setStyleSheet("QTextEdit, QListWidget{\n"
"border: 2px solid #666;\n"
"background-color: #3b3b3b;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
"}\n"
"QListWidget QScrollBar\n"
"{\n"
"background : gray;\n"
"color: black\n"
"}\n"
"")

        self.listWidget.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.listWidget.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Plain)
        self.listWidget.setLineWidth(1)
        self.listWidget.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAsNeeded)
        self.listWidget.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAsNeeded)
        self.listWidget.setSizeAdjustPolicy(QtWidgets.QAbstractScrollArea.AdjustIgnored)
        self.listWidget.setAutoScroll(True)
        self.listWidget.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        self.listWidget.setTabKeyNavigation(False)
        self.listWidget.setProperty("showDropIndicator", True)
        self.listWidget.setDragDropOverwriteMode(False)
        self.listWidget.setAlternatingRowColors(False)
        self.listWidget.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoSelection)
        self.listWidget.setSelectionBehavior(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SelectItems)
        self.listWidget.setTextElideMode(QtCore.Qt.ElideNone)
        self.listWidget.setVerticalScrollMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.ScrollPerItem)
        self.listWidget.setHorizontalScrollMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.ScrollPerItem)
        self.listWidget.setMovement(QtWidgets.QListView.Static)
        self.listWidget.setFlow(QtWidgets.QListView.TopToBottom)
        self.listWidget.setProperty("isWrapping", False)
        self.listWidget.setResizeMode(QtWidgets.QListView.Adjust)
        self.listWidget.setLayoutMode(QtWidgets.QListView.SinglePass)
        self.listWidget.setViewMode(QtWidgets.QListView.ListMode)
        self.listWidget.setUniformItemSizes(False)
        self.listWidget.setWordWrap(True)
        self.listWidget.setSelectionRectVisible(False)
        self.listWidget.setObjectName("listWidget")
        
        self.lineEdit_2.raise_()
        self.lineEdit_3.raise_()
        self.lineEdit_4.raise_()
        self.lineEdit_5.raise_()
        self.pushButton_5.raise_()
        self.pushButton_7.raise_()
        self.smile_1.raise_()
        self.smile_2.raise_()
        self.smile_3.raise_()
        self.smile_6.raise_()
        self.smile_5.raise_()
        self.smile_4.raise_()
        self.smile_9.raise_()
        self.smile_8.raise_()
        self.smile_7.raise_()
        self.pushButton.raise_()
        self.listWidget.raise_()
        self.frame_2.raise_()
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Chat by Liemore"))
        self.lineEdit_2.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ваше сообщение"))
        self.lineEdit_3.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "Порт"))
        self.lineEdit_4.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "IP"))
        self.lineEdit_5.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ник"))
        self.pushButton_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Подключиться!"))
        self.pushButton_7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Светлый режим"))
        self.smile_1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", ""))
        self.smile_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", ""))
        self.smile_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", ""))
        self.smile_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", ""))
        self.smile_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", ""))
        self.smile_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", ""))
        self.smile_9.setText(_translate("MainWindow", ""))
        self.smile_8.setText(_translate("MainWindow", ""))
        self.smile_7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", ""))
        self.title1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Чат для общения"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "X"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "_"))
        
        self.listWidget.setSortingEnabled(False)
        
        
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.listWidget.setWordWrap(True)                           # !!! +++

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.button_clicked)
        
    def button_clicked(self):
        text = self.lineEdit_2.text()
        width = self.listWidget.fontMetrics().width(text)

        index = 0
        _list = []
        while index != -1:
            index = text.find(' ')
            if index == -1:
                width = self.listWidget.fontMetrics().width(text)
                if width > 550:
                    _text = f'{text[0:len(text)//2]} {text[len(text)//2:]}'
                    _list.append(_text)                    
                else:
                    _list.append(text)
            else:
                i = index + 1
                _text = text[0:index]
                if self.listWidget.fontMetrics().width(_text) > 550:
                    _text = f'{_text[0:len(_text)//2]} {_text[len(_text)//2:]}'
                _list.append(f'{_text} ')
                text = text[index + 1:]


        text = ''.join(_list)
        self.listWidget.insertItem(0, text)
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы просто лучший! Спасибо!

Comment: А невозможно ли сделать так, чтобы если сообщение было на 3+строки, он бы разделял еще и еще и еще

Comment: @Tynett пожалуйста. Я думаю, что все возможно. Задавайте новый вопрос, публикуйте ваш пример, который демонстрирует проблему и хорошо объясните, что вы хотите сделать и что у вас не получается.

Comment: @Tynett что не так?

Comment: Проблема в том, что если юзер напишет сообщение свыше 2 строк, оно будет добавлять новый scrollbar и делать некрасивым и неюзабельным чат. Возможно ли сделать так, чтобы оно делило если бы было 4+

Answer (score 0):

Небольшой тестовый пример (Работает для `PyQt5`, `PySide2`, `PySide6`):

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QFrame, QTextEdit, QListWidgetItem, QListWidget, QPushButton, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QSizePolicy
from PyQt5.QtGui import QTextOption, QFont
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

# Кастомный виджет для вставки в строку QListWidget
class ListRowWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ListRowWidget, self).__init__()

        lay = QHBoxLayout()
        lay.setMargin(0)
        self.dummy = QWidget()
        self.dummy.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.edit = QTextEdit()
        self.edit.setFrameShape(QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.edit.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        font = QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.edit.setFont(font)
        self.edit.setReadOnly(True);

        # Перенос строки, если не хватило места
        self.edit.setWordWrapMode(QTextOption.WrapAnywhere)

        # Выключаем вертикальный скролбар       
        self.edit.verticalScrollBar().hide()

        self.setLayout(lay)

    # Сообщение
    def setText(self, text):
        self.edit.setText(text)

    # Выравнивание
    def setAlignment(self, alignment):
        if self.layout().count() > 0:
            self.layout().removeWidget(self.dummy)
            self.layout().removeWidget(self.edit)

        if alignment == Qt.AlignLeft:
            self.layout().addWidget(self.dummy)
            self.layout().addWidget(self.edit)
        else:
            self.layout().addWidget(self.edit)
            self.layout().addWidget(self.dummy)

    def size(self):
        return self.edit.document().size().toSize()

class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Widget, self).__init__()

        self.load_ui()

        self.sendButton.clicked.connect(self.send)
        # Флажок для "выравнивания" сообщения (вправо-влево, поочередно)
        self._side = False

    def load_ui(self):        
        self.listWidget = QListWidget()
        self.sendButton = QPushButton("Отправить")
        self.textEdit = QTextEdit()
        font = QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.textEdit.setFont(font)
        self.textEdit.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Preferred)

        hLay = QHBoxLayout()
        hLay.addWidget(self.textEdit)
        hLay.addWidget(self.sendButton)

        vLay = QVBoxLayout()
        vLay.addWidget(self.listWidget)
        vLay.addItem(hLay)
        self.setLayout(vLay)

    def send(self):
        # Получаем текст из поля ввода
        text = self.textEdit.toPlainText()

        # Итем для вставки в список 
        listItem = QListWidgetItem() 
        self.listWidget.addItem(listItem)

        # Наш кастомный виджет отображения сообщений чата
        listRowWidget = ListRowWidget()
        # Передаем в него текст
        listRowWidget.setText(text)

        # Выравнивание в соответствии с "какой стороны пришло" сообщение
        listRowWidget.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft if self._side else Qt.AlignRight)
        self._side = not self._side

        # Помещаем наш виджет вместо итема
        self.listWidget.setItemWidget(listItem, listRowWidget)

        # Устанавливаем размер строки списка
        listItem.setSizeHint(listRowWidget.size())                

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    widget = Widget()
    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Результат:

[image: пример чата PyQt5 PySide2 PySide6]